# Are this two version of Bezout theorem (for curves) equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am trying to understand (and prove) the Bezout theorem for curves. For this reason, I am mainly focusing in [Dathan Ault-McCoy "On Bezout Theorem"](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_20/papers19/Dathan.pdf) and in [Willian Fulton "Algebraic Curves"](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf).

The Bezout theorem is stated in a different manner in this documents.

In Ault-McCoy, it is stated as:

> Let $f, g \in k[x, y, z]$ be nonzero coprime homogenous
> polynomials of orders $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then $ \#( f ∩ g) = mn.$

On the other hand, In Fulton, it is stated as:

> Let $F$ and $G$ be projective plane curves of degree $m$ and $n$
> respectively. Assume $F$ and $G$ have no common component. Then
> $$ \sum_P I(P,F \cap G ) = mn. $$

My main question is: are this two ways of stating the Bezout theorem actually equivalent?

When looking at other references, most of the autors statement of the Bezout theorem coincide with the Fulton's one. So... my question is: is there a way to relate nonzero coprime homogeneous polynomials of orders $m$ and $n$ to projective plane curves that have no common components?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, provided you take the right definitions, these are the same. Ault-McCoy should be counting with multiplicity (i.e. the unique intersection point of $V(y)$ and $V(y-x^2)$ should count twice) and Fulton's definition of a plane curve will translate exactly to a homogeneous polynomial, and the condition that they have no common component is exactly that the defining polynomials are coprime.